# meteorite cant run metorite npm error

Tags: meteor, meteorite

when i do this:

```
$ mrt create myapp
$ cd myapp
$ mrt
```

i get this error message:
livedata: updating npm dependencies -- sockjs, websocket...
No dependency info in bundle. Filesystem monitoring disabled.
=> Errors prevented startup:
Exception while bundling application:
Error: Command failed: npm WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-smartpackage-livedata@0.0.0 No README.md file found!

i have this from the new "discover meteor" book by sasha greif.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try: $mrt create myapp -> $cd mypp -> $meteor

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem as I was following through the Discover Meteor book as well.  It might be the same error you are having but I can't remember it exactly, it was rather long and suggested running mrt as root/administrator.  Also, I'm not sure if the error I was having was related to the version of Node.js that I was using (0.10.6 on Ubuntu).

Thanks to a comment posted on github by Apendua (https://github.com/apendua) I was able to run mrt successfully without having to run as root/administrator.

Here is what he found:

"What I've seen so far is the follwing. After calling:

sudo npm install -g meteorite
there is a mysterious tmp dir in my home with content owned by root. I don't think it's distribution specific since I've experienced this on Ubuntu 12.10 as well as on Ubuntu 13.04. Also, the content of .npm dir in my home is sometimes - but sometimes it is not - owned by root. Getting rid of tmp and changing privilages on .npm solevd the issue for me. No need to sudo mrt any more."